# $http saving result with callback function

Tags: angularjs

`myCallback()` will be executed once the response is received and `console.log(scope.mediafiles)` returns `undefined`.
I need to display `scope.mediafiles`.

```
foo = function(callback) {
  $http(method: "get", url: "http://myhost/bananas", options = {}).success(callback)}

myCallback = function(result) {
  scope.mediafiles = result
  console.log(scope.mediafiles) // it will output the result
}

foo(myCallback);

console.log(scope.mediafiles) // output undefined
```

[@AlekseySolovey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8495123/aleksey-solovey) Even if I read the documentation, I still do not understand.

```
mydata.then(function(res){scope.mediafiles = res;});
```

returns

[image]

Thanks a lot for your Support!

Comment: `.success` is deprecated use `.then` instead.

Comment: `console.log(scope.mediafiles)` is _undefined_ because it is called **before** `myCallback`, since that one is asynchronous (where the data can arrive in few milliseconds or in several minutes). Keep your logic within the callback

Comment: @AlekseySolovey ok, that means doing everything inside `myCallback = function(result) { // my code logic }`. What If I need this data to be utilized in other functions? How can I get it out of the scope `function myCallback(result) { scope.mediafiles = result }`

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio return the data instead: `foo = (callback) => {return $http.get(url).then(callback);}` with `myCallback = (result) => {return result.data;}`. **Note** both `return` used for the Promise (`$http.get` request) and the response. Then you need to resolve the promise every time you need the data: `foo(myCallback).then((res) => {scope.mediafiles = res;})`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey thanks. in this case `mydata = foo(myCallback)` will return `Promise {$$state: {…}, success: ƒ, error: ƒ}`. I would need it to return the `response.data`

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio yup, that's a Promise that `$http` request returns, so just resolve it: `mydata.then(function(res){scope.mediafiles = res;});`